# wp7 quickly localizing a ton of strings in app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, localization, resx

I have an app where I am trying to localize about 100 strings into 15+ languages. When it comes to using resx in visual studio, I can only copy/paste into one cell at a time. Naturally, I don't want to have to do this 1500 times.

Is there a way/program where I can use to take all my translated strings, and just copy/paste them into the entire cell column, one time each for the 15+ languages I have?

I tried Resex, but at face value it doesn't look like I can do that? Maybe I am just using it wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: I do recall some Visual Studio extensions that assist with this (though it was a while ago and I can't remember what they were at all). Beyond those, the resx file is just an XML file, so you can take a look at the formatting and maybe do some quick copy/pasting, find/replace, or write a simple script to build the XML content for you.

Comment: interesting as I didn't know it's an xml file. I shall take a look into this

Comment: Thank you for this comment, Chris Sinclair. I was able to utilize both formats to make this a painless process for me. You and Igor Kulman are both awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get it a CSV file (e.g: export from Excel) I have a simple tool to convert the CSV to a RESX file: http://lostintranslation.apphb.com/ (select CSV to bundle and .NET)